# Can't return nil, but zero value of slice

Tags: go

I am having the case in which a function with the following code:

```
func halfMatch(text1, text2 string) []string {
    ...
    if (condition) {
         return nil // That's the final code path)
    }
    ...
}
```

is returning `[]string(nil)` instead of nil. At first, I thought that perhaps returning `nil` in a function with a particular return type would just return an instance of a zero-value for that type. But then I tried a simple [test](http://play.golang.org/p/SLxcRyavm7) and that is not the case.

Does anybody know why would `nil` return an empty string slice?

Comment: Your test case works as expected and returns nil. Can you produce a test case which behaves like the code you have problem with ? Chances are you have an error in your logic and are returning somewhere else.

Comment: I will try to make it into a better test case, but before the `return` that I believe is returning `nil`, I have a `Println` that gets printed, so it must be that `return` statement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nil is not a type. It is a description of the zero value for maps, chans, pointers, functions,                 slices, and interfaces.

When you put "nil" in your program, go gives it a type depending on the context. For the most part, you never need to explicitly type your nil. This is no exception, the compiler knows it must be a []string(nil) because the type returned is []string.

A nil string slice is a slice with no backing array and a length/capacity of zero. You may compare it to the literal "nil" and can get its length and capacity. It is a []string, just empty. If you wish to have an empty []string that is not nil, return []string{}. This creates a backing array (of length zero) and makes it no longer equivalent to nil.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I know what's going on. The assert library I am using ([github.com/bmizerany/assert](http://github.com/bmizerany/assert)) is using internally a `reflect.DeepEqual`.

The return value of `func halfMatch(text1, text2 string) []string` is always of type `[]string`, but if it returns `nil` and is compared to a `nil` value via the `==` operator, it will return `true`. However, if `reflect.DeepEqual` is used, the type will matter and it won't consider both values the same.

[playgound link with the test](http://play.golang.org/p/JSyc3VOF9k)

Comment: I think you're right. As `DeepEqual` takes two `interface{}` values, `reflect.DeepEqual(test1(""), nil)` will result in `DeepEqual` getting  `[]string{}` (zero string slice) and `interface{}` (zero interface value), which will fail due to mismatched types.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are being confused by the output of print. ([playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/V0ugBlnRCH))

```
package main

import "fmt"

func f() []string {
    return nil // That's the final code path)
}
func main() {
    result := f()
    fmt.Printf("result = %v\n", result)
    fmt.Printf("result = %v\n", result == nil)
}
```

Which produces

```
result = []
result = true
```

So I think the output really is `nil`

Comment: Actually my assertion fails: `assert.go:24:  ! []string(nil) != nil`

Answer (score 0):

Go will return an enpty slice if condition is true.

There is a problem with your "test" because if you try to compare [] with nil, you get true. 
I have modified your test to show you what I mean

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    //fmt.Println(test1("") == nil)  
    fmt.Println(test1("")) // prints [] 
}

func test1(text1 string) []string {
    if len(text1) > 0 {
        return []string{text1}
    }
    return nil
}
```